# Android SearchActivity doesn't search

Tags: android, search

I have implemented Search option into my app, and it works fine in every activity, only thing where is not working is in SearchActivity (activity that shows search results) could someone tell me why

Here is code of my SearchActivity and Manifest:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv;
ArrayList<Proizvod> proizvodi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSearchResoult);

    handleIntent(getIntent());

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Proizvod pom = (Proizvod)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("izabrani", pom);
            intent.putExtra("proizvodi", proizvodi);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())){

    }else if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())){
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResoults(query);
    }

}

private void showResoults(String query){
    proizvodi = new ArrayList<Proizvod>();
    ProizvodTableAdapter dbAdapter = new ProizvodTableAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.open();
    proizvodi = dbAdapter.getProizvdi(query);
    dbAdapter.close();
    lv.setAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(proizvodi,this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.search:
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.katalog"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.katalog.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowPicture"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PicturesActivity"></activity>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchActivity" />
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```